# Append image next to <a> in CSS

Tags: html, css

im not sure what is the correct approach for this with css.

I have an element like this in my design.

[image: menu]

What i have right now, are 2 "a" elements, and one of this have an .active class.

```
    <div class="botones_menu">
        <a href="#" class="active">Mis anuncios publicados</a>
        <a href="#">Publicar nuevo anuncio</a>
    </div>
```

What i need to do is to append this image:

[image: arrow]

next to the "a" element with the .active class

```
.botones_menu { padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;}
.botones_menu > a { font-weight: normal; font-size:12px; color:#FFF; background-color: #00652e; display: block; padding: 10px; padding-left: 30px; border:1px solid #9faca5; margin-left:2px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
.botones_menu > a.black {background-color:#000;}
.botones_menu > a.active { background-color: #6bb90f; background-image: url(imagenes/green_arrow.png); background-position: right; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Note that you can make [triangles with pure CSS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had not noticed the CSS style before so i had to rework my previous codepen.

Here is the new Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYzqGq

HTML

```
<div class="botones_menu">
    <a href="#" class="active">Mis anuncios publicados</a>
    <a href="#">Publicar nuevo anuncio</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.botones_menu {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.botones_menu > a {
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #6BB90F;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border:1px solid #9faca5;
  margin-left:2px;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.botones_menu > a.black { background-color:#000; }

.botones_menu > a.active {
  background-color: #6BB90F;
  height: 16px;
}

.botones_menu a.active:after {
  content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WRHT.png');
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  left: 100%;
  top: -30px;
  margin-left: 11px;
}
```

Comment: This was really close to the correct answer! With a few changes it works pefect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a CSS background image:

```
.active {
   display:block;
   background-image:url(...);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   width:200px;
   background-position:180 0;
   padding-right:20px;
}
```

Adjust padding, width and background position to suit your image.

Comment: Look at my css. This was my first approach, but since i already have a background color, the element appears over the background, and i need it to look outside the background.

Comment: Using :after or : before might be better for your case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pseudo element. If you give your active (or both) menu items a right hand margin, you could have a pseudo element positioned to the right of it.

You'd need to also change the `position` of the active menu item:

```css
.botones_menu {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.botones_menu > a {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color: #00652e;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border:1px solid #9faca5;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.botones_menu > a.black {
    background-color:#000;
}
.botones_menu > a.active {
    margin-right:17px; /* Image width */
    position:relative;
    background-color: #6bb90f;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.botones_menu > a.active:after {
    display:block;
    width:17px;  /* Image width */
    height:35px;   /* Image height */
    content:'';
    right:-17px;   /* -(Image width) */
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WRHT.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="botones_menu">
  <a href="#" class="active">Mis anuncios publicados</a>
  <a href="#">Publicar nuevo anuncio</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogvavv

Use the :before pseudo-selector for CSS like this:

```
.botones_menu a.active:before {
  content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WRHT.png');
}
```

Comment: i've tried with :after selector, but the image is appended inside the element, next to the text. Nothing like what i need to do.